# SQLite query (and subqueries) for lagging a column by group

Tags: sql, r, sqlite

I have a **SQLite** table `myTable` with some 3.2 billion records.  It has records of workers's status (0 or 1) in companies over time. The same worker can be in different companies. The table looks like this:

```
companyID   workerID    timeVar     workerStatus
-------------------------------------
1           1           1           0
1           1           2           0
1           1           3           0
1           1           4           1
-------------------------------------
1           2           3           1
1           2           4           1
1           2           5           0
1           2           6           0
-------------------------------------
2           1           1           1
2           1           2           1
2           1           3           1
2           1           4           0
-------------------------------------
2           2           1           1
2           2           2           1
2           2           3           0
2           2           4           0
2           2           5           0
2           2           6           1
-------------------------------------
```

Note that `companyID`, `workerID`, `timeVar` are keys.

I want to create two columns:

1. `workerStatusMaxLag1` will say whether `workerStatus` in the immediate previous `timeVar` was equal to 1.
2. `workerStatusMaxLag2` will say whether `workerStatus` in the two immediate previous `timeVar` was equal to 1.

To be clear, this is what I am trying to achieve:

```
companyID   workerID    timeVar     workerStatus    workerStatusMaxLag1     workerStatusMaxLag2
1           1           1           0               NULL                    NULL
1           1           2           0               1                       1
1           1           3           0               1                       1
1           1           4           1               1                       1
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           2           3           1               1                       1
1           2           4           1               1                       1
1           2           5           0               1                       1
1           2           6           0               0                       1
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
2           1           1           1               NULL                    NULL
2           1           2           1               1                       1
2           1           3           1               1                       1
2           1           4           0               1                       1
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
2           2           1           1               NULL                    NULL
2           2           2           1               1                       1   
2           2           3           0               1                       1
2           2           4           0               1                       1
2           2           5           0               1                       1
2           2           6           1               0                       1
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### Note

Workers can move across companies, and that the two new columns in this table vary only within `workerID` and `timeVar`, but not across `companyID`, save for the fact that `timeVar` can be different for each combination of company x worker.

I am working in **R**, but given that my data is so large, I think I am safer if I do all of this with SQL statements alone, and not load (slices of) the data into **R**.

### What have I tried

I am new to SQL and I have tried to give some baby steps, but have not gone too far. I think the first step in building my query is to

```
SELECT companyID, workerID, timeVar, MAX(workerStatus)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY workerID, timeVAR
```

So that I know `workerStatus` in each period. Then I thought of joining this back to the table, but first I need to calculate the lags.

I have looked but didn't go very far. Also, there might be different approaches and performance may vary considerably. While I don't need top performance (I will do this one time only), I do have a pretty heavy table (3.2 billion rows, or a 100GB+ table worth of data), and I just don't want my machine to crash (I'm on Windows 7, 16GB RAM, Intel i7-2600).

Comment: Your sample data doesn't match your rules.  For the first block, the values are "1", but the status is "0".

Comment: @GordonLinoff, they do match the rules; worker 1 has status 1 in periods 1-3 in company 2 (see the third block). The new columns aren't about companies; they are about workers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *express* the query using correlated subqueries.  For instance, to get the previous status

```
select t.*,
       (select t2.status
        from myTable t2
        where t2.companyId = t.companyId and 
              t2.workerId = t.workerId and
              t2.timeVar < t.timeVar
        order by t2.timeVar desc
        limit 1
       ) 
from myTable t;
```

This query really wants an index:  `myTable(companyId, workerId, TimeVar, Status)`.

Even with the index, though, 3.2 billion rows is pretty big for such a complicated query.  I don't know if SQLite will complete.

Comment: many thanks. but I am getting syntax error near t2... am I doing something wrong? I literally copied/pasted your code and table/column names are exactly the same.